# Converting Kinect Methods from Beta 2, to Version 1

Tags: c#

So I have convert the `getDisplayPosition` from the beta version of the Kinect SDK to the full version. Here's what I have right now

#### The Original

```
 private Point getDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        nui.SkeletonEngine.SkeletonToDepthImage(joint.Position, out depthX, out depthY);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));  //convert to 320, 240 space
        int colorX, colorY;
        ImageViewArea iv = new ImageViewArea();
        // only ImageResolution.Resolution640x480 is supported at this point
        nui.NuiCamera.GetColorPixelCoordinatesFromDepthPixel(ImageResolution.Resolution640x480, iv, (int)depthX, (int)depthY, (short)0, out colorX, out colorY);


        // map back to skeleton.Width & skeleton.Height
        return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
    }
```

#### My Version

```
private Point getDisplayPosition(Joint joint)
    {
        float depthX, depthY;
        KinectSensor sensor = kinectSensorChooser1.Kinect;
        DepthImageFormat depth = DepthImageFormat.Resolution320x240Fps30;
        depthX = 320;
        depthY = 240;
        sensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depth);
        depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
        depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));
        int colorX, colorY;
        colorX = 320;
        colorY = 240;

        return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
    }
```

Basically I want to know if my version will do the same thing as the origin

Comment: Hmm, I think to would be better received at [SO]. This isn't really a "please review my working code" question but more of a "help me get this updated to the current version" question which doesn't really fit here.

Comment: @Mercado Oh I was gonna ask it there but didnt know if it would fit. Thanks!

Comment: @Mercado can you add a `kinect` tag, I have insufficient rep to do so, and is kinda necassary

Comment: I found some information here
http://everythingyoumightneed.blogspot.com/2012/11/complete-guide-converting-code-from.html

for other similar subjects aswell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I have this same question on Stack Overflow now, the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10367582/converting-kinect-methods-from-beta-2-to-version-1/10448663#10448663). The updated version is:

```
private Point getDisplayPosition(DepthImageFrame depthFrame, Joint joint)
{ 
    float depthX, depthY;        
    DepthImagePoint depthPoint = kineticSensor.MapSkeletonPointToDepth(joint.Position, depthImageFormat);

    depthX = depthPoint.X;
    depthY = depthPoint.Y;

    depthX = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthX * 320, 320));
    depthY = Math.Max(0, Math.Min(depthY * 240, 240));

    int colorX, colorY;
    ColorImagePoint colorPoint = depthFrame.MapToColorImagePoint(depthPoint.X, depthPoint.Y, sensor.ColorStream.Format);
    colorX = colorPoint.X;
    colorY = colorPoint.Y;

    return new Point((int)(skeleton.Width * colorX / 640.0), (int)(skeleton.Height * colorY / 480));
}
```